# Drawing Image wrong size WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, height

I'm drawing a cell wall on a map and it is the wrong size. I checked the height of the image in debugger and it was the same size as the cellSize which is correct, but visually it appears shorter and the start of it is not drawn in the correct place. Like it is being drawn over top of at both ends. When I change the Height property of the image it does not make the image bigger. Is that not how to set the image size, with Height and Width?

[image]

Here is the code.

```
private void calculateWall(int wall, int cell)
        {
            int[] mapData = this.getMapData(cell);
            int startOfCol = mapData[0];
            int endOfCol = mapData[1];
            int startOfRow = mapData[2];
            int endOfRow = mapData[3];
            CellSide rightSide = this.getCells()[cell].myRightWall;
            CellSide bottomSide = this.getCells()[cell].myBottomWall;

            float thickness = myMap.myCellSize * (float)0.1;
            Math.Round(thickness, 0);
            int newThickness = Convert.ToInt32(thickness);

            float height = myMap.myCellSize * (float)0.2;
            Math.Round(height, 0);
            int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(height);

            if (rightSide.hasWall == 1)
            {
                Image verticalWall = new Image();

                // Create source.
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

                // BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block.
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.UriSource = new Uri("verticalWall.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                bi.EndInit();

                // Set the image source.
                verticalWall.Source = bi;

                verticalWall.Width = newThickness;
                verticalWall.Height = myMap.myCellSize;
                verticalWall.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToDouble(startOfRow));
                verticalWall.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToDouble(endOfCol - (newThickness / 2)));

                verticalWall.IsHitTestVisible = false;
                this.view.pbxMap.Children.Add(verticalWall);
            }
```

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Create a proper ViewModel and use an `ItemsControl` for this.

Comment: @HighCore I'm dynamically adding and deleting walls on mouse click. No problems with this technique in my winforms version.

Comment: WinForms ain't WPF, and regardless, I'm actually interested in what you're doing (as in, would like to see the end result :)

Comment: @Noctis Yes but I've been drawing the walls programmatically in WPF too, as well as other images, in this way, and it has worked, so I would prefer to do it this way, but it is weird how it's not working this time. That's cool, I can give you the github url when it's finished if you like :)

Comment: @user2602079 do that :) . Sorry I can't offer more help on this. Having said that, what's the problem of using the XAML  and binding to handle the clicks? Sometimes it's much easier and shorter to do things in XAML rather than in code ...

Comment: @Noctis Will do. That's ok! Well i'm sure that is a good way, probably better practice, but i'm trying to get it done quickly as it's the last task I have, and I would prefer to go with a way I already know how to do and have used throughout my app, so I can move on.

Comment: @user2602079 You need to learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore Oh bugger. My teacher suggested i do a quick conversion of my MVC winforms app to WPF. No wonder i have found WPF so bad for games. It is fully converted however, successfully, except for the walls looking bad. I drew other images this way so theoretically this should work

Comment: @Noctis Here is the github url https://github.com/btf271/newGroupWPF  I will delete this message when you reply. Right click to add/delete cells to make different shaped maps. Left click to add/delete walls. Click and drag Theseus, Minotaur, and stairs onto the map. Essentially this is a Level Designer for Theseus and the Minotaur, the puzzle game, and was my class assignment, not to make the game play module or the module to save the maps to be played in game play. Thanks for taking an interest in my work! :)

Comment: :) . Interesting. here's a bug, [extra line](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpp10plm8hbmbi6/2013-10-30%2009_29_18-Design%20a%20Level.png) sometimes. I would suggest adding ability to move Minotaur and guy by dragging them from current position, but if it's only an assignment never mind. I would recommend looking more at MVVM, and also adding comments to your code, and structuring your folders better (for example, put all your images in a "images" folder in the solution). It'll make your life easier on big projects :).

Comment: @Noctis yes that dragging would be better but I think i won't bother as it's a class assignment. Yes all your suggestions are very good and i should. I did try structuring better but when i moved my things into folders my program could no longer find them. The extra line is not a bug, that is a wall, click all over the lines to add or delete walls and that is where the theseus and minotaur cannot pass through in a game.

Comment: You should probably have added the folder to your path or something. True about the walls, i thought the empty squares are walls, my bad :). No worries, and I guess you can remove this now, if you're done :)

Comment: @Noctis I moved the .cs files into folders such as model and view too to be more structured, but i didn't know how to fix those errors. Do you think that is an issue needing to write a path somewhere? Thanks for looking at the app and offering some sound advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you programmatically draw an image in WPF, its stretch property is set to uniform by default. Add this line:

```
verticalWall.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
```

Now it will size correctly even if it does not stretch uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your last questions in the comments.

Ok, here's a screenshot of how I structured your project: Screenshot [image]

Now, wherever you use any of the pictures,you'll have to add the folder to that path:

```
Source="exit.png"
```

Will become:

```
Source="/Images/exit.png"
```

This:

```
<Page.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="marbleBackground.jpg"/>
</Page.Background>
```

Will become:

```
<Page.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/marbleBackground.jpg"/>
</Page.Background>
```

And so on ... problem solved :)

Comment: Thanks very much! So, you didn't change any paths in regard to moving the .cs files? That caused errors for me, but if you did it just then then i must be able to.

Comment: Nope. Just created the folder and dragged them in ... I was about to suggest some version control, but you're using GIT, so you have a backup anyways. Feel free to try it :)

Comment: Thanks :) yes i'm using Git, but sometimes i make new repos for various reasons, i have about 10 repos leading up to this final product. I am no good with accessing previous versions in a git repo. But i cannot ask you every question under the sun, you have helped a lot! Thanks, i will try it :-)

Comment: True, true ... you could always just zip your solution, and then fiddle with it. If it doesn't work, restore from the zip. Another option I'm using and am happy with is [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.net/). If you found this helpful and it answered your question, you can mark it as the solution as well.

Comment: Ok thank you :) yes it was helpful, i may leave this question unanswered for a bit to see if anyone has a solution to my code without changing the architecture of my program to MVVM, but i know i should, however i won't :P I don't have time. But thank you very much!

Comment: I changed my folder structure to your one and it worked but it cannot locate startScreen.xaml. So i had to disable "just my code". And i did. But it's now asking me to change existing PDB and binary search path patterns. I don't think i should mess with settings. How come MainWindow.xaml and App.xaml don't work when shifted to another folder?

Comment: I think because it's expects them to be at a specific entry point, and it searches from there. I usually have the mainwindow and app.xaml in the root of the project ...

Comment: Makes sense. Works perfectly with your structure + StartScreen.xaml out of any folder. Thanks

Comment: Lol, I don't have an answer for the original question. I will try to solve it myself, and if the answer I find is not going to help anyone, or if I ask a new question about it, I will change the original question to this question and mark this as the answer :)